# VS2015 executable become virus (with potential solution but don't know why)

Tags: c++, mfc

This is one of the weirdest things ever happen to me in my programmer career.

I am working on a MFC project, and recently my antivirus software BitDefender sees my executable as virus " `Gen:Variant.Razy.47148`"

Here is the scan result from `virustotal.com`

```
Antivirus   Result  Update
ALYac       Gen:Variant.Razy.47148  
Ad-Aware    Gen:Variant.Razy.47148  
Arcabit     Trojan.Razy.DB82C   
BitDefender Gen:Variant.Razy.47148  
Emsisoft    Gen:Variant.Razy.47148 
F-Secure    Gen:Variant.Razy.47148  
GData       Gen:Variant.Razy.47148  
eScan       Gen:Variant.Razy.47148
```

*the rest are clear result

I have a few configurations, this happens to only one of them. So I then compare the setting difference, turns out `Linker--Debugging--Generate Debug Info` is the problem. When it is "No", not virus, when it is Yes, virus.
Then I look at what exactly it does, it says "This option enables creation of debugging information ofr the .exe file or the DLL." 
Detailed description from MS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe4t6fc1.aspx
I don't see any possible way this make my executable become virus.

More you might want to ask:

1. Hard drive scanned clear by multiple well-known antivirus program.
2. Executable is clear if I turn that to "No" without doing any other changes. Which means that all those .c and .h I included are clear.
3. I know this is kind of like a false positive virus since only some "unnamed" antivirus software report this. BUT unfortunately, I have to use BitDefender, and some of those computer that my program will be running at are using it as well.(my program is just a debugging tool for internal use only)

Comment: .h can't contain viruses. they're just headers. .c could contain a virus, but then they'd have to be infected with SOURCE CODE of a virus.

Comment: Report it to the people who make Bit Defender as a false positive. This isn't a programming issue, it's a "crappy virus checker" issue.

Answer (score 5):

If nothing else on your hard drive is being flagged as malware by your antivirus, then this "detection" is most probably because *something* in your program is triggering a heuristic detection routine inside the AV.

This "something" might be a string you've used, a particular sequence of machine instructions, or even a function name. The fact that the AV would no longer flag your program when you turn off the debug information might suggest that the trigger is indeed something that would get stripped off in a non-debug build (e.g. function names.)

This is not a compiler bug or something that can be solved by them. You can (and should) report your executable file as a false positive to the AV vendor (the exact file that is being reported as having a virus.)

As I said before, this is not - in all probability - a real infection, so you needn't worry about that after the steps you've already taken.

You've mentioned that when you build your program without debug info, it will not be flagged or reported by the antivirus. Can you ship your program without debug information? This is how almost all software gets distributed anyways. If you can, then you're in the clear with your users; your debug-info-less program will not be reported as a virus.

Comment: Debug info gets compiled into separate PDB files. Whether you create debug info or not, the executable image will always be debug-info-free (unless you explicitly request debug information to be placed into the binary). Any sane developer on Windows does create debug information for software that gets released.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sure, sure. But you don't ship them to your customers. Also, I'm looking forward to an alternate explanation of what is happening here.

Comment: Of course you don't ship your PDBs. But your statement about *"debug-info-less program[s]"* is still wrong. Turning debug information on or off doesn't (or shouldn't anyway) change code generation. Debug information doesn't go into the executable, that's flagged as containing a virus.

Comment: @IInspectable, well, something should explain this behavior, and there are parts of the debug information (symbol names, source file names, etc.) that do go into the executable. Also, there are various formats for debug information, and some might add things to the EXE.

Comment: *"parts of the debug information (symbol names, source file names, etc.) that do go into the executable"* - I don't believe that's accurate. Symbol names go into an executable for imports and exports. They are there, irrespective of debug information. Source file names won't go into executable images. The path to the PDB does (and that is a difference, that could trigger a false positive).

Answer (score 1):

Could there be some telemetry/"phone-home" going on that virus scanners are detecting?  See this blog [posting](https://itnerd.blog/2016/06/10/fail-visual-studio-2015-inserts-code-into-complied-apps-that-phones-home/) for more info on that discovery in VS2015.

Comment: Interesting.  The reddit thread contained remarks from an MSVC manager who said that linking "notelemetry.obj" would disable this.  I've tried this today with VS2019.  It does not prevent a Bitdefender trigger, unfortunately.  As of now the only thing that prevents it is to leave debug info out of the build.  Which is OK (kind of) for a release build.   But it isn't OK for a debug build.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter, thank you so much for the tip about "Linker--Debugging--Generate Debug Info".  In case there is any doubt about this being a false positive issue, I happened upon this thread while trying to prove I hadn't infected my workstation.  The problem happened when I created a simple VS2015 project (Win32 Console Application) without adding the headers for ATL or MFC.  The program contained only the boilerplate code generated by the template.

Virus was detected by Symantec Endpoint Protection as Heur.AdvML.B.

Strangely, adding the headers for ATL and/or MFC produces an exe with "no virus".

Also, creating a similar project in VS2013 (without ATL/MFC) also produces an exe that is "clean".

Hope this helps somebody else to not waste half a day hunting.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: I just did, but I'm not sure specifically what was wrong with my "answer".  I was prohibited from commenting (reputation score) and thought I provided thanks, context and specifics.  Of course I may not be smart enough to post here :)

Comment: I second the false Symantec detection of "Heur.AdvML.B".  Disabling "Generate Debug Info" resolved it.  But still not a complete solution :-/